# ssh-agent is not used when ssh is launched from panel launcher (via `gnome-terminal --command`)

Tags: ssh, xfce-panel, ssh-agent

I have everything [set up](http://relief.zxcvb.cz/cgi-bin/blosxom.cgi/how_i_set_up_my_ssh-agent_2.html) so that after I log in and add proper identity to ssh-agent using `ssh-add` from a gnome-terminal window, I do not have to enter the passphrase again when I invoke `ssh myserver`.

Now I wanted to make it even easier and create a panel launcher that would run

```
gnome-terminal --command "ssh myserver"
```

but while this does invoke what I want, it ignores ssh-agent, i.e. it *asks for pass-phrase*.  And it does so every time, even if I supply the PP, the next time it asks again.

What am I doing wrong?  Can anybody explain why this does not work?

---

Further notes:

- Running `gnome-terminal --command "ssh myserver` from already open terminal works OK
- Changing `ssh myserver` part to `bash -c "ssh myserver"` with proper quoting
  did not help.
- Also using `ssh myserver` right in the launcher did not help: the pass-phrase prompt
  was displayed as a simple GUI window (unless I checked "Run in terminal" option,
  in which case the behavior was same as described above)
- It's Ubuntu 12.04
- adding -vvv to both ssh command, here is where the failing (and asking for PP) ssh
  starts to differ from the successful ssh:

  ```
  [...]
  debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
  debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 5e:ad:5e:1f:7f:...
  debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
  debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
  Enter passphrase for key '/home/lennycz/.ssh/id_rsa':
  ```

  while the successful ssh says

  ```
  [...]
  debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
  debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 5e:ad:5e:1f:7f:...
  debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
  [...]
  ```

  (and then lot of things apparently unrelated...)

  I haven't found any helpful debug messages around nor anything in system/auth logs.

Comment: I assume you are aware that it will always ask for a passphrase the first time it's run, right?  So, what version of Ubuntu are you using?  I had a similar (or maybe same) problem with 11.10, but with 12.03 it is working correctly, using the same command as you.  I'm using Gnome Classic/Fallback/whatever it's called, and created a simple panel app launcher.  EDIT:  sorry, I decided to look at your link, and I'm not doing anything at all like that.  What is the purpose of that code over the standard setup?

Comment: FWIW, the method I use is to run `ssh-keygen -t rsa` for the client machine, then to copy the key to the remote system, I run `ssh-copy-id <username>@<hostname>`, assuming RSA and standard port 22.  If not standard, there's a slight variation.  I've used the ssh-agent method for cygwin in the past, but never needed it for Ubuntu for a long time.

Comment: @MartyFried Thanks for interest. I put some answers right in the Q.  For the rest: A) I expect it to ask for PP only after I invoke ssh-add, then all subsequent ssh processes load it from ssh-agent. B) I'm not sure what you mean by "standard" way. What you describe in your 2nd comment is the auth part, which I've already done correctly (hence the `ssh myserver` works from previously opened terminal window).  My problem is about ssh-agent, specifically that ssh, when invoked via launcher does not use it while ssh invoked from terminal window does.

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken, or simply forgot the details, but I thought that with ssh agent, you only needed to enter the PP once _per session_, and it then saved you from entering it every time you needed to do things like scp, etc.  This is what I get automatically with Ubuntu, without any extra work.  I don't remember, but perhaps at one time I decided that this was good enough, so I never needed more.  If you want to never enter a PP even once, then I'm sorry I can't help.

Comment: @MartyFried I was expecting it to work like on my GUI-less Debian/Squeeze server: you run ssh-add, enter the PP and then use all ssh's and scp's and git pull/pushes without need to enter PP again.  (Basically what you say except that on my box I explicitly need to call ssh-add.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you followed the linked article and modified your `~/.bashrc`. However `~/.bashrc` might never be sourced when you're running a command from a panel launcher.

An easy way to debug is adding `date > /tmp/bashrc_sourced` to then end of your `~/.bashrc` and check if the current time is printed to the file when you invoke the panel launcher.

Related note: You might want to look at [keychain](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/keychain.1.html), which is specifically designed to manage ssh-agent for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest verifying that SSH_AUTH_SOCK is passed correctly.

I have this as part of my login script in KDE:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${HOME}/.ssh-agent.sock"
rm -f ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
ssh-agent -a ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
```

and this in my .bashrc:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${HOME}/.ssh-agent.sock"
```